# how to use current username in sql command

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am trying to get some data from the database. I need the name specific data from the database. How can i return the current Drupal user name and use it in WHERE statement.
The error message is

```
error:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause'.
```

and my current code is

```
global $user;
$cuname = $user->name;

$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);
$grid->SelectCommand = "SELECT uid,name,created,company_id FROM users WHERE company_id = (SELECT company_id FROM users WHERE name = $cuname)";
```

Comment: What if `$cuname` is something like `'' OR 1 = 1; -- `? You really don't want that... seriously

Comment: my current username is admin

Comment: @BeratÇelik: What EliasVanOotegem commented is on [*SQL Injection*](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: It is weird that when i print $cuname it displays 'admin' yet i cannot use it in sql :s

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around stirngs.

```
SELECT company_id FROM users WHERE name = '$cuname'
                     here-----------------^-------^
```

Otherwise the DB things you mean a column name. BTW you should consider using *Prepared Statements* to avoid such errors and SQL injections.

Comment: And you should/must use the appropriate string literal encoding function before putting $cuname _into_ the sql query.

Comment: When i use the  '$cuname' instead of  $cuname
it says
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Answer (score 0):

Don't write your sql queries - do it "drupal way". Use views module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/views

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use db_select (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) or db_query (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7)

example for db_select:

```
<?php
global $user;

$select = db_select('users', 'u'); 
$select->fields('u', array('uid', 'name'));
$select->condition('user', $user->name);

$result = $select->execute()->fetchAssoc();
?>
```